# Passing both table and single argument to same function in SpecFlow

Tags: c#, specflow

I have a step-function that adds a number to a calculator:

```
private readonly List<int> _numbers = new List<int>();
...
[Given(@"I have entered (.*) into the calculator")]
public void GivenIHaveEnteredIntoTheCalculator(int p0)
{
    _numbers.Add(p0);
}
```

I can call it from the feature file using this syntax:

```
Given I have entered 50 into the calculator
```

But I also want to call the same function using a table, in which case the function should be called once for each row of the table:

```
@mytag
Scenario: Add multiple numbers
    Given I have entered 15 into the calculator
    Given I have entered <number> into the calculator
        | number |
        | 10     |
        | 20     |
        | 30     |
    When I press add
    Then the result should be 75 on the screen
```

Which should be equivalent to:

```
@mytag
Scenario: Add multiple numbers
    Given I have entered 15 into the calculator
    And I have entered 10 into the calculator
    And I have entered 20 into the calculator
    And I have entered 30 into the calculator
    When I press add
    Then the result should be 75 on the screen
```

That is, the `And` clause with a table and the `Given` clause without a table call/reuse the same function, only the clause with a table calls it multiple times. At the same time, the other clauses are called only once - not once per row, which I think is different from using a Scenario Context.

This doesn't work, however. I get the following error:

> TechTalk.SpecFlow.BindingException : Parameter count mismatch! The binding method 'SpecFlowFeature1Steps.GivenIHaveEnteredIntoTheCalculator(Int32)' should have 2 parameters

The only way I can make it work is using a table - `public void GivenIHaveEnteredIntoTheCalculator(Table table)`, but I wanted to use a table without having to rewrite the function.

Comment: Use a [scenario outline](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-outlines) for the second test. The keyword "Scenario outline:" is required in this case.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you, I looked into the link you provided, but I think that what I am looking for is slightly different. I have edited my question, does it make things clearer?

Comment: Yes, but in that case you really will need a second function of some form, no way around it. You can't express multi-step operations with a shorthand directly in SpecFlow/gherkin, you'd need to tweak the language. A simple workaround is to change your grammar for the second case ("Given I have sequentially entered `<numbers>` into the calculator"), with the second method taking a `Table` and simply calling the first method in a loop. I'd arguably call this clearer for the reader as well. This kind of delegating helper method can be very useful.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the answer. I will be using the workaround you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call one step from another step.

First, the Scenario:

```
Scenario: Add multiple numbers
    Given I have entered the following numbers into the calculator:
        | number |
        | 15     |
        | 10     |
        | 20     |
        | 30     |
    When I press add
    Then the result should be 75 on the screen
```

Now the step definition:

```
[Given("^I have entered the following numbers into the calculator:")]
public void IHaveEnteredTheFollowingNumbersIntoTheCalculator(Table table)
{
    var numbers = table.Rows.Select(row => int.Parse(row["number"]));

    foreach (var number in numbers)
    {
        GivenIHaveEnteredIntoTheCalculator(number);
    }
}
```